# WooCommerce: Change order status based on custom Meta Value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to run the following function daily, to auto-complete all processing order older than 10 days and who have a specific custom meta value.

I'm using the following snippet, however this will simply not work. Any idea as to why?

```
function autoComplete(){
    $orders = wc_get_orders( array(
            'status' => 'wc-processing',
            'date_created' => '<' . ( time() - 10 * DAY_IN_SECONDS ),
            'meta_key'     => 'status_us',
            'meta_compare' => '=',
            'meta_value'   => 'Sent to USA',
    ) );

    foreach ($orders as $order){
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}

if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'autoComplete' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'autoComplete' );
}
```

Is there any error I've missed? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did a good attempt but you made a few mistakes.

The following code goes inside your `functions.php`.

```php
add_action( 'wp_loaded','start_custom_code' );

// Once everything theme and plugins are loaded we register our cron job.
function start_custom_code() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'bks_mark_processing_order_complete_if_sent_to_usa' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'bks_mark_processing_order_complete_if_sent_to_usa' );
    }
}

add_action( 'bks_mark_processing_order_complete_if_sent_to_usa', 'bks_mark_processing_order_complete_if_sent_to_usa' );
```

Your function has minor errors `bks_mark_processing_order_complete_if_sent_to_usa()`

```php
function bks_mark_processing_order_complete_if_sent_to_usa(){
    $args = array(
        'status' => array( 'wc-processing'),
        'limit'  => -1,
        'date_created' => '>' . ( time() - 864000 ), // your mistake 1
        'status_us' => 'Sent to USA', // your mistake 2
    );


    $orders = wc_get_orders( $args );

    foreach ($orders as $order){
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
        $order->save(); // your mistake 3
    }
};
```

Mistake Explanations

1. While your attempt was in right direction but `'date_created' => '<' . ( time() - 10 * DAY_IN_SECONDS ),` you had to use `>` instead of `<` also you didn't acutally set `DAY_IN_SECONDS` You had to replace it with 86400. So the correct value would be `'>' . ( time() - 864000 )`. For 10 days `10 * 86400 = 864000`. You can read about this explanation [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#parameters) in the WooCommerce documentation.
2. Here I have created new custom variable for you which is set using `woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query` and then queried. Code that needs to be added.

```php
function handle_custom_query_var( $query, $query_vars ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['status_us'] ) ) {
        $query['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'status_us',
            'value' => esc_attr( $query_vars['status_us'] ),
        );
    }

    return $query;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query', 'handle_custom_query_var', 10, 2 );
```

3. You updated the status but you forgot to save it. `$order->save();`

So to summarise you have to add the following code in your functions.php

```php
add_action( 'wp_loaded','start_custom_code' );
add_action( 'bks_mark_processing_order_complete_if_sent_to_usa', 'bks_mark_processing_order_complete_if_sent_to_usa' );


function start_custom_code() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'bks_mark_processing_order_complete_if_sent_to_usa' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'bks_mark_processing_order_complete_if_sent_to_usa' );
    }
}

function bks_mark_processing_order_complete_if_sent_to_usa(){
    $args = array(
        'status' => array( 'wc-processing'),
        'limit'  => -1,
        'date_created' => '>' . ( time() - 864000 ),
        'status_us' => 'Sent to USA',
    );


    $orders = wc_get_orders( $args );

    foreach ($orders as $order){
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
        $order->save();
    }
};

function handle_custom_query_var( $query, $query_vars ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['status_us'] ) ) {
        $query['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'status_us',
            'value' => esc_attr( $query_vars['status_us'] ),
        );
    }

    return $query;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query', 'handle_custom_query_var', 10, 2 );
```

**The above code is TESTED and WORKS.**

Proof:
[image]

Install [WP CRON plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/) to check your cron. See above screenshot. You can test by hitting `Run Now`.

> **Caveat :** 
> WP Cron runs, when somebody visits your website. Thus if nobody visits, ?>the cron never runs.
>
> Read this : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/179774/204925

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great explanation. However, for some reason the function is doing anything. I can also see the cron-job listed, but when I run the job, nothing happens. I've tested it multiple times...can you please confirm you have tested the code, not just the cron-job?

Comment: Hey @JohnSmith, I forgot to add a hook which would bind the cron and the function it has to run. I have updated my answer and also double checked it again. Please try again.

Comment: This line doesn't make sense:
`add_action( 'bks_mark_processing_order_complete_if_sent_to_usa', 'bks_mark_processing_order_complete_if_sent_to_usa' );`

Comment: Okay, I see the code (function) is working, however the cron job isn't. Do you know why it would not work?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the cron is not working ?

Comment: When I run the cron-job every 1-2 mins I can see nothing happens. However, the function is working properly as I ran it manually (not through a cron-job).

Comment: Okay, when you set cron to run every 1-2 mins you will have to change the `wp_schedule_event` from daily to the interval you want. Once that is set it should start to run after that interval, but the way wordpress cron works is different. In the wordpress cron documentation (https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/ ) you can see this line it reads `WP-Cron does not run constantly as the system cron does; it is only triggered on page load.` So every time someone visits a page WP checks for pending cron and runs it. Please read the Caveat I added in my answer.

Comment: @JohnSmith, use `cron_schedules` https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/understanding-wp-cron-scheduling/ to create your custom cron intervals. WordPress only has hourly, twicedaily, daily and weekly interval out of the box.

Comment: Hey @JohnSmith, does my answer not solve your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do to validate orders based on a CRON task.

```
$order->payment_complete('transaction ID string'); //validate payment
wc_reduce_stock_levels($order->get_id()); //reduce stock
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); //empty cart
$order->update_status('completed', 'A order note string'); //change order statyus
```

I believe that you don't need the "wc-" prefix.

Are you sure that your scheduled event is working? and that `$orders` is filled? Please test your method without the schedule first.