# Update order status from custom statuses to completed in WooCommerce everyday at 23.00 if meta_key = Delivery Date and meta_value = this day

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cron, orders

I am trying to make a Function, that automaticly updates the Post status to Completed if the status is wc-ishoej-afhentning, wc-roskilde-afhent, wc-koege-afhentning, wc-soeborg-afhent or wc-birkeroed-afhent. But it can only change the status, if a metakey(Delivery date) in postmeta is == the meta value of the Delivery date is == The current date.

This is an image of the values from every order in the database
[image: Values from the database]
I believe the format is j F, Y

I am really hoping someone could help me.. i have some different codes, which i have been looking at trying to figure it out myself, but i seem to get nowhere.

First code below, this one i found on stackoverflow, but can seem to figure out how to change it into what i need.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'update_order_status_on_monday' );

function update_order_status_on_monday() {

    if ( date( 'D', strtotime( 'now' ) ) === 'Mon' && !get_transient( '_updated_order_status_on_monday' ) ) {

        $processing_orders   = wc_get_orders( $args              = array(
            'numberposts'    => -1,
            'post_status'    => 'wc-processing',
        ) );

        if ( !empty( $processing_orders ) ) {
            foreach ( $processing_orders as $order )
                $order->update_status( 'completed' );
        }
        set_transient( '_updated_order_status_on_monday', true );
    } elseif ( date( 'D', strtotime( 'now' ) ) !== 'Mon' ) {
        delete_transient( '_updated_order_status_on_monday' );
    }
 }
```

The second code, i one i am currently using to change to the custom statuses, which i have added here below

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_ishoej_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_ishoej_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }
    
    if( get_post_meta($order_id, 'Pickup Location', true ) == "Ishøj" ) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'wc-ishoej-afhentning' );
        
    } elseif ( get_post_meta($order_id, 'Pickup Location', true ) == "Roskilde" ) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'wc-roskilde-afhent' );
        
    } elseif ( get_post_meta($order_id, 'Pickup Location', true ) == "Køge" ) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'wc-koege-afhentning' );
        
    } elseif ( get_post_meta($order_id, 'Pickup Location', true ) == "Søborg" ) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'wc-soeborg-afhent' );
        
    } elseif ( get_post_meta($order_id, 'Pickup Location', true ) == "Birkerød" ) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'wc-birkeroed-afhent' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I recently answer somewhat similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67755204/8298248 - Does this help ?

Comment: @Bhanu It look kinda simaler, but not exactly, i have to take a post meta value, and check if it the date is the current day, and if it is true it need to change to complete

For example, i made an order, where in the database,
`meta key = Delivery Date` 
And
`Meta Value = 9 Juni, 2021`

And what i need is, that if the current date is 9 juni, and it is 11 in the night, it need to automatic update this orders status to completed. 

I hope this is making sence

Comment: Okay, I think just the validation is different. Please update your question with the following. What is the `meta_key` ( It can't be `Delivery Date` that's label )? What is the format of date in that meta key ? ( It is needed for comparision). What's the limit of orders it has to search for at 11PM? Ideally it can search for all the orders but it can get slow.  Also please add the status names in english as well for generall understanding.

Comment: Hello Bhanu, There is no limit, it has to change all pickup location(afhentning) statuses orders if the date, is the delivery date that the customer put in the order.  I am not shure if i understod correct, but i added an image from how it looks in the post meta, and also the format which i think is in.

So if today was the 9. juni 2021 then at 11pm the orders status would need to change the status to completed.

Hope i am clear, otherwise i am more than ready to try and explain furthere :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it should be done. Go through the code carefully. I have added comments for you to understand what every function does.

```php
/*
 * Trigger the code when everything is loaded.
 * */
add_action( 'wp_loaded','start_custom_code' );


/*
 * Set a cron job for daily Midnight.
 * */
function start_custom_code() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'bks_delivery_to_complete' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( (strtotime('midnight') + (3600 * 23)) , 'daily', 'bks_delivery_to_complete' );
    }
}

// Plug the cron job with function 'bks_mark_order_complete_if_delivered_today'
add_action( 'bks_delivery_to_complete', 'bks_mark_order_complete_if_delivered_today' );


/*
 * This function selects order with wc-processing status and with orders
 * having meta key 'Delivery Date' set as current date.
 * */
function bks_mark_order_complete_if_delivered_today(){

    $args = array(
        'status'        => array( 'wc-processing'), // Add any other statuses order of which you want.
        'limit'         => -1,
        'delivery_date' => date("d M, Y"), // Use Current date to fetch Orders.
    );

    $orders = wc_get_orders( $args );

    foreach ($orders as $order){
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
        $order->save();
    }
};

/* This functions add a new key 'delivery_date'
 * which enables user to pass date to check against
 * Meta Data 'Delivery Date'.
 * */
function bks_handle_custom_query_var( $query, $query_vars ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['delivery_date'] ) ) {
        $query['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'Delivery Date',
            'value' => esc_attr(date("d M, Y") ),
        );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query', 'bks_handle_custom_query_var', 10, 2 );
```

**Things to keep in mind :-**

- We are using [wordpress cron job](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/), and according to the doc `WP-Cron does not run constantly as the system cron does; it is only triggered on page load.` and as the code is set to run at 11 O`Clock every night if somone doesn't visit your website the cron job will not run. And once the date passes, the code will be applicable for other day. Solution to this is to use system crons. [ *Google to set system crons intead of wordpress cron, they are more reliable.*]
- According to your question your meta tag is `Delivery Date`, it should be strictly followed or else because an error won't select the order and it will be missed. so `Deliver  Date` ❌ (with two spaces) wont work `Deliver date` ❌ (Small d for date). I guess you understand what I am saying.
- Date has to strictly follow "d M, Y" format. Which means today is `05 Jun, 2021` not `5 Jun, 2021`. It is a string comparision. If the meta data is set using a code I don't think there could be a problen.
- I couldn't understand the statuses that you suggested so I have just used processing for now. You can add others in `bks_mark_order_complete_if_delivered_today()` function.

The code is tested and WORKS.

Install [WP CRON plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/) to check your cron. You can test by hitting Run Now.

This question is worth looking at when working with wp_cron https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/179774/204925

Comment: Hello Bhanu, This is working perfect, but the setting midnight, isent that at 00.00 hours.

I am trying to make the system cron to call the website at the right time, but i am confused weather to run it at 11/23 or at 12/24/00(Different times in different formates 12h and 24h clock)

Hoping you can help with this! :D

Does thisn look correct
https://gyazo.com/cc819097825e13d34219a070e6cbdcc0

Comment: Well midnight is always the at the start of the date. i.e. 00:00 that's why i added 23 hours on top of that. I am unable to understand your screenshot. Can you send that in english if possible ?

Comment: Well the problem is the time is beyond 23.00 24h format, and i am having trouble figuring out how to make a server cron as you talked about in the answer

Comment: And if i press run now, it works perfectly. So my question is, how do i actually get it to run at 23 a clock my time(Denmark) - The screenshot was from our plesk server, i will tomorow try to se if i can fix it in english :)

Comment: And i also just figured out that i might be because we are in denmark, and we are running utc +2

Comment: Hello @bhanu

It seems like this has all of a sudden stopped working, do you maybe know the reason why?

Comment: That's a very vague information for me to debug it. It can happen due to a lot of reasons, 1.  CRON not working 2. Error in your code. I would sugges you to look in you debug.log file.

Comment: thanks for the fast Answer, where is the debog.log file located? :)

Comment: Nevermind, i found it :) - And i cant seem to send my code in comments :/ - So you could check if something i wrong ;)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ Use this service.

Comment: Well why didnt i think of that :D - Here it goes, this is the code https://pastebin.com/suFQjigW
And here is the debug.log: https://pastebin.com/UU7Ne388 - i cant seem to find any errors but the cronjob is not being running, and even if i press run now it does not seem to run :'(

Comment: If it's not running when you press run now, then it is for surity that the issue is with the code. Setup a development server and, dump orders that are fetched from the qurery. Hit Run Now then and see the orders that are returned.

Comment: So make a Clone of the site, and make some orders, that i can test on? :)

Comment: Yes, use https://laragon.org/ for windows (googel if Mac) and setup the website locally. YOu can use duplicator plugin to do that.

Comment: Well that is all good, but then my next problem is, that i dont understand how to make vardump and stuff like that in wordpress

Comment: Hey I wrote a blog on how to debug wordpress, https://bhanusingh.in/efficient-debugging-workflow-for-wordpress-developers This should help you.